# Скрытие места для рекламы AdMob, когда нет соединения с интернетом

Tags: android, admob

Когда нет интернета, то нет же и рекламы, а само место для рекламы пустое и занимает место на экране. Нужно чтобы когда отсутствует интернет, то основное содержимое страницы раздвигалось и занимало пустое место для рекламы.
Уверен, многие такое делали в своем приложении. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, готовым кодом. Уже неделю ищу в интернете и ничего найти не могу.

Нашел стандартный код в официальном руководстве:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
        { @Override public void onAdLoaded() { 
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } });
```

Но что с ним сделать, чтобы он работал, не знаю. Если у вас есть готовый код, был бы очень благодарен.

Сделал вот так:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
    { @Override public void onAdLoaded() { 
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE); } });
```

Но ничего не заработало. Если отключаю интернет, то вместо рекламы просто пустое место. Вот его я и хочу убирать, когда нет инернета.

**ВСЕМ КТО ИЩЕТ ОТВЕТ НА ТАКОЙ ВОПРОС САМ ДЕЛЮСЬ ТЕПЕРЬ РЕШЕНИЕМ:**

Это код АдМоба с изначальной скрытостью:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
android:visibility="gone" 
ads:adUnitId="ваш_id" />
```

а это ставим в Активити.ява:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
        { @Override public void onAdLoaded() { 
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } });
```

Все, больше ничего, все работает. Пользуйтесь)

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо создать layout так, чтобы по умолчанию этот блок не показывался именно так, как надо. А если реклама загружается, то блок показывается. Изучите параметры функции View.VISIBLE|INVISIBLE|GONE.